# C++ 2Dimensional array

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning c++,and the code went so far,until
i made array variables to call a function instead of string,but something went wrong,and i can't figure out what it is.Problem is,it couts correctly only first 2 letters,then it couts the rest as └└└└ symbols.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>



using namespace std;



int land(){
    HANDLE hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_GREEN);
    char H = 72;
    cout<<H;
}

int player(){
    HANDLE hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    char X = 88;
    cout<<X;
}

    /*previously,i declared a string inside worldgen,and generated 2d array inside the for loop,but when i changed variables to call a function,first letters were X and H,but then it went └└└└└└└└└└└└└└└└└└└└└└└ for all the remaining characters.What's wrong here? */

int worldgen(int dimX,int dimY,int x,int y){  
    HANDLE hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    system("TITLE MyTitleText");
    int H = land();
    int X = player();
    string world[dimX][dimY];
    for(int c = 0;c<dimY;c++){
        for(int count = 0;count<dimX;count++){
            world[count][c] = H;
            world[x][y] = X;
            cout<<world[count][c];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


}




int main(){
    HANDLE hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    worldgen(70,15,10,10);

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: That's not standard C++, by the way (apart from the obvious winapi). If the array declaration works, it's a compiler extension.

Comment: @chris I cannot see why you say so.

Comment: @AnalogFile, Variable-length arrays are not part of the language. The code may already not be portable across operating systems, but that's no reason not to make it not portable across compilers.

Comment: @OP, Seeing as how you're already using the Windows Console API, [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050(v=vs.85).aspx) would be a better substitute than `system("title")`.

Comment: Oh, I missed that dimX and dimY were parameters. I just took them as global constants. You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Neither land() nor player() return anything so neither H nor X are getting any meaningful data are are just garbage data that was uninitialized.

I'm surprised this is even compiling since you have two functions that are supposed to return ints but aren't set to return anything.